# How can I inherit from a class but override a static property?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a database with a lot of tables, but most of them have the same structure. They all have an `Id:int` column, and a `Name:string` column.

I am writing C# classes to represent each Object in these tables, but since they all have `Id, Name` I decided to make them implement an interface.

```cs
public interface IIdWithName
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to do CRUD operations in the database, I end up copying a lot of the code and only changing the table names.

I tried to make each class inherit from a base class that has a `virtual TableName`, but I can't make the property static, and it doesn't make sense to have the property of TableName be not static, especially for cases when I try to get a list of Objects from the class.

This is what I tried:

```cs
public class BaseClass : IIdWithName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static string TableName { get; }

    public static IEnumerable<IIdWithName> ReadAll()
    {
        string sql = $"select * from {TableName}";

        // ... more code to read objects from db and return IEnumerable
    }
}

public static SubClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public static string TableName => "SubClass1TableName";
}
```

The above code compiles fine, but when I try to call `SubClass1.ReadAll()`, the method runs, but the property `TableName` is not set to `SubClass1TableName`, but is `null`.

How can I inherit from a base class, but override only the static property?

If that's not the correct thing to do, then what can I do to reduce duplicating CRUD code in this case?

Comment: Static members don't participate in polymorphism - there's no such thing as "overriding" a static method or property. Additionally, I'd expect a call to `SubClass1.ReadAll()` to actually end up being compiled to `BaseClass.ReadAll()` in the first place.

Comment: *"it doesn't make sense to have the property of TableName be not static"* Why? You have and will have only one table?

Comment: @JonSkeet so what can I do to acheive my goal?

Comment: See answers from other posters - I only had time to point out why your current approach wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design confuses rows with tables. You have a `class BaseClass` and a `class SubClass1 : BaseClass` which represent rows, but they are also trying to somehow expose table functionality. That's untenable. It will never work.

A row contains fields and it is supposed to have no other functionality.  A table contains rows, and exposes functionality for querying, which yields rows.

Once you properly split things into classes that make proper sense, you will have no more problems of this kind.

In other words, you need a `class BaseRow` and then `class SubRow1 : BaseRow` etc, and then you ***also*** need a `class BaseTable` and a `class Table1 : BaseTable` etc.  Each table may have a private constructor and expose a `public static BaseTable Instance = new Table1();` or you may instantiate them explicitly and keep them somewhere for easy access.

Comment: Your answer makes the most sense. I have already adopted the proposed logic and I don't know why I have never thought of this before.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 11 you can use [static abstract methods in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) to implement something similar. For example:

```
public interface IIdWithName
{
    // ...

    static abstract string TableName { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IIdWithName
{
    // ...
    static string IIdWithName.TableName => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    
    public static IEnumerable<T> ReadAll<T>() where T : IIdWithName
    {
        string sql = $"select * from {T.TableName}";

        // ... more code to read objects from db and return IEnumerable
        Console.WriteLine(sql);
        return default;
    }
}

public class SubClass1 : BaseClass, IIdWithName
{
    public static string TableName => "SubClass1TableName";
}
```

With usage like:

```
var result = BaseClass.ReadAll<SubClass1>();
```

Probably it worth splitting the interface `IIdWithName` into two so the `BaseClass` does not have to implement the `TableName`.

But personally I would consider some other design. Probably just using an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) instead of writing your own one.